# SQL query in my JAVA program done using Prepared statement throwing error despite being correct

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, xampp

In my java programs , I am trying to do insertion ooperation in MySQL table using prepared statements .

Here it my SQL query:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = null;

String sql="INSERT INTO registration"+"(phone,name,address,city,destination,date) VALUES"+ "(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

try{
    //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
    //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //STEP 3: Open a connection
    System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
    stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    //STEP 4: Execute a query
    System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
   // stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.setInt(1, phone[i]);
    stmt.setString(2, name[i]);
    stmt.setString(3, address[i]);
    stmt.setString(4, city[i]);
    stmt.setString(5, destination[i]);
    stmt.setString(6, date[i]);

    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
}catch(SQLException se){
    //Handle errors for JDBC
    se.printStackTrace();
}catch(Exception e){
    //Handle errors for Class.forName
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    //finally block used to close resources
   try{
        if(stmt!=null)
            conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
    }// do nothing
    try{
        if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }//end finally try
}//end try
System.out.println("Goodbye!");
break;
```

I cant seem to find any error in the SQL query , yet the program is throwing a syntax error . Here is the complete program for context ,if you need;

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

    public class Airplane {
        // JDBC driver name and database URL
        static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/airplane";

        //  Database credentials
        static final String USER = "root";
        static final String PASS = "";

    public static void main(String args[])
    {   int i=0;int choice;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String name[]=new String[1000];
        String address[]=new String[1000];
        int phone[]=new int[1000];
        String city[]=new String[1000];
        String destination[]=new String[1000];
        String date[]=new String[1000];

        do {

            System.out.println("WELCOME TO AIRPLANE MANAGEMENT SYSTEM");
            System.out.println("Select your operation :");
            System.out.println("1:New Booking");
            System.out.println("2:List");
            System.out.println("3:Search");
            System.out.println("4:Edit");
            System.out.println("5:Delete");
            System.out.println("6:Bill");

            choice = sc.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("Enter your Phone number:");
                    phone[i] = sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Enter your name:");
                    name[i] = sc.nextLine();


                    System.out.println("Enter your address:");
                    address[i] = sc.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Enter your Pick up city:");
                    city[i] = sc.nextLine();


                    System.out.println("Enter your Destination:");
                    destination[i] = sc.nextLine();


                    System.out.println("Enter your Date:");
                    date[i] = sc.nextLine();
                    ++i;
                    Connection conn = null;
                    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

                    String sql="INSERT INTO registration"+"(phone,name,address,city,destination,date) VALUES"+ "(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                    try{
                        //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
                        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                        //STEP 3: Open a connection
                        System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
                        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                        System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
                        stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                        //STEP 4: Execute a query
                        System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
                       // stmt = conn.createStatement();
                        stmt.setInt(1, phone[i]);
                        stmt.setString(2, name[i]);
                        stmt.setString(3, address[i]);
                        stmt.setString(4, city[i]);
                        stmt.setString(5, destination[i]);
                        stmt.setString(6, date[i]);

                        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                    }catch(SQLException se){
                        //Handle errors for JDBC
                        se.printStackTrace();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        //Handle errors for Class.forName
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally{
                        //finally block used to close resources
                       try{
                            if(stmt!=null)
                                conn.close();
                        }catch(SQLException se){
                        }// do nothing
                        try{
                            if(conn!=null)
                                conn.close();
                        }catch(SQLException se){
                            se.printStackTrace();
                        }//end finally try
                    }//end try
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                    break;
                }


                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Name\tAddress\tContactNo\tPickUp City\tDestination\tDate");
                    for (int m = 0; m < i; m++) {
                        System.out.println(name[m] + "\t" + address[m] + "\t" + phone[m] + "\t" + city[m] + "\t\t" + destination[m] + "\t" + date[m]);

                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("enter the contact number to see details");
                    int search=sc.nextInt();
                    for (int m = 0; m < i; m++) {
                        if(search==phone[m])
                        System.out.println(name[m] + "\t" + address[m] + "\t" + phone[m] + "\t" + city[m] + "\t" + destination[m] + "\t" + date[m]);

                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;

                case 5:
                    break;
                case 6:
                    break;

            }
        }while(choice!=0);



    }//end main
    }//end JDBCExample
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

The program is showing this error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?)'
>   at line 1     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1540)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2595)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1468)
>     at Airplane.main(Airplane.java:90)

Comment: I do see some potential problems with your JDBC code, but that error seems to have to do with the connection to MySQL itself not being correct.  Are you sure your connection string is right?

Comment: Unrelated but you need to call `i++` after you execute SQL query or you will use empty values because ones you've got from user have index `i`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated my question . Please see it . I only have one error now . I had not started the sql server via XAMPP , that is why I was getting connection error .Now I have only error .Can you see it ?

Comment: You might need to add some whitespace to your insert query, i.e. use this: `INSERT INTO registration (phone, name, address, city, destination, date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I did not reject any of your edits

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels fixed it . Thanks for the edits

Comment: Please format stack traces as `CODE` and not as a blockquote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be here:

`stmt.executeUpdate(sql);`

You have already given the raw string query to the statement here:

`stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);`

The `PreparedStatement` version of `executeUpdate()` takes no parameters.  Looks like you are hitting the version in the `Statement` interface inherited by `PreparedStatement` that runs the string passed in as the parameter.

I think it will work if you remove the sql string from the call:

`stmt.executeUpdate();`

Comment: And yeah, your call stack shows this, because you are hitting `StatementImpl`, not something like `PreparedStatementImpl`.

Comment: Thankssssssssssss  mate !It worked . I have been working on this for 2 days

Comment: Glad to help.  Been there myself, many times.  Good luck.